# How to write Aggregate function on Map<String, float> to calculate MIN, MAX and AVG based on key value

Tags: java, cassandra

I have element cloumn which is of type MAP in cassandra

```
elements = [{"a":10,"b":12,"c":13,"d":14},{"a":2,"b":1,"c":5,"d":19},{"a":5,"b":4,"c":13,"d":4},{"a":140,"b":1,"c":4,"d":14}]
```

I want to write a aggregated function in java which find min max of Map Keys and the result will be.

```
[{a "min": 2, "max": 140},{b "min": 1, "max": 5},{c "min": 4, "max": 13},{d "min": 4, "max": 19}]
```

I have never written this stuff. Need Help.

Comment: have you looked to https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/cql/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDA.html, http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2015 & http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=1876 ?